# How to set flags for difference between dates and another identifier?

Tags: sas

My data is structured like this:

```
ID  admission  discharge  loc_num lagdish
A   08Oct15    12Oct15    0001      -
A   13Oct15    21Oct15    0002     12Oct15
A   12Nov15    16Nov15    0003     21Oct15
A   01Dec15    03Dec15    0004     16Nov15
B   03Aug15    08Aug15    0001     03Dec15
B   03Aug15    08Aug15    0007     08Aug15
C   14Sep15    17Sep15    0003     08Aug15
C   17Sep15    17Sep15    0003     17Sep15
```

The rule is that if the current admission and previous discharge are 1 day apart or less, they should be rolled-up into one episode but only if the loc_num is the same.  If the loc_num is different, it will still be considered two episodes.  Some IDs have the same admission and discharge, but different loc_nums and this should be considered one episode (so same flag).

So ideally the flagged table would look like this:

```
ID  admission  discharge  loc_num lagdish         flag
    A   08Oct15    12Oct15    0001      -           1
    A   13Oct15    21Oct15    0002     12Oct15      2 
    A   12Nov15    16Nov15    0003     21Oct15      3
    A   01Dec15    03Dec15    0004     16Nov15      4
    B   03Aug15    08Aug15    0001     03Dec15      1
    B   03Aug15    08Aug15    0007     08Aug15      1
    C   14Sep15    17Sep15    0003     08Aug15      1
    C   17Sep15    17Sep15    0003     17Sep15      1
```

So for ID A, although the difference is 1 day between 12Oct15 to 13Oct15, the loc_num is different, therefore they are distinct episodes.  For ID C, because the difference is 0 days AND the loc_num are the same, it's considered the same episode.

```
proc sort data=have; by ID admission; run;

data want;
set have;
flag=1;
do until (last.ID);
set have_orig;
by ID admission;
lagdisch=lag(discharge);
if first.id=0 then do;
if admission > lagdisch+1 then admission+1;
else admission+0;
end;
output;
end;
run;
```

I used this to flag for combining episodes without considering loc_num, so it would flag any episodes within an ID that were 1 day apart or less between the current admission and previous discharge.  But I haven't figured out how to modify it so that it takes into account slightly different rules to set the flags.

Addition:

```
ID  admission  discharge  loc_num lagdish  
F   10Apr15     14Apr15   0003     -
G   30Apr15     30Apr15   0002     14Apr15
G   01May15     06May15   0002     30Apr15
G   08Sep15     12Sep15   0002     06May15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested for different conditions. Try this out and let me know in case you face any difficulties in understanding any part of the code.

```
data have;
    input id $ admission date9. discharge date9. loc_num 5.  lagdish date9.@;
    format admission date9. discharge date9. lagdish date9.;
    cards;
a   08oct15 12oct15 0001   -
a   13oct15 21oct15 0002 12oct15
a   12nov15 16nov15 0003 21oct15
a   01dec15 03dec15 0004 16nov15
a   01dec15 03dec15 0005 03dec15
b   03aug15 08aug15 0001 03dec15
b   03aug15 08aug15 0007 08aug15
c   14sep15 17sep15 0003 08aug15
c   17sep15 17sep15 0003 17sep15
d   17sep15 17sep15 0003 17sep15
d   18sep15 19sep15 0004 17sep15
e   17sep15 17sep15 0004 19sep15
e   18sep15 19sep15 0004 17sep15
f   10apr15 14apr15 0003     -
g   30apr15 30apr15 0002 14apr15
g   01may15 6may15  0002 30apr15
g   08sep15 12sep15 0002 06may15
g   15sep15 16sep15 0002 06may15
;
run;

data have1(drop=lagdish lag_adm lag_dis lag_loc);
    set have;
    format lag_adm date9. lag_dis date9.;
    by  id;
    lag_adm = lag(admission);
    lag_dis = lag(discharge);
    lag_loc = lag(loc_num);

    if first.id then
        do;
            lag_adm = .;
            lag_dis = .;
            lag_loc = .;
        end;

    if intck("days",admission,lag_dis) in (-1,0,1) and loc_num = lag_loc then
        flag=1;

    if admission = lag_adm and discharge=lag_dis then
        flag = 1;
run;

proc sort data= have1 out=have2;
    by  descending id  descending admission descending flag;
run;

data have3;
    set have2;
    by descending id;
    lag_flag=lag(flag);

    if first.id then
        lag_flag=.;
    flag1 = compress(flag||lag_flag,'. ');
run;

proc sort data=have3 out=have4(drop=lag_flag flag);
    by id admission flag;
run;

data want1;
    set have4(where=(flag1='1'));
    indicator=1;
run;

data want2;
    set have4(where=(flag1 not ='1'));
    by id;

    if first.id then
        indicator=1;
    indicator+1;
run;

data want(drop=flag1);
    set want1 want2;
run;

proc sort data=want;
    by id admission;
run;
```

**My Output:**

```
ID  admission   discharge   loc_num INDICATOR
A   08Oct2015   12Oct2015   1       2
A   13Oct2015   21Oct2015   2       3
A   12Nov2015   16Nov2015   3       4
A   01Dec2015   03Dec2015   4       1
A   01Dec2015   03Dec2015   5       1
B   03Aug2015   08Aug2015   1       1
B   03Aug2015   08Aug2015   7       1
C   14Sep2015   17Sep2015   3       1
C   17Sep2015   17Sep2015   3       1
D   17Sep2015   17Sep2015   3       2
D   18Sep2015   19Sep2015   4       3
E   17Sep2015   17Sep2015   4       1
E   18Sep2015   19Sep2015   4       1
F   10Apr2015   14Apr2015   3       2
G   30Apr2015   30Apr2015   2       1
G   01May2015   06May2015   2       1
G   08Sep2015   12Sep2015   2       2
G   15Sep2015   16Sep2015   2       3
```

Comment: I tested this out on my dataset, but for an ID with the same loc_num and one day apart in current admission and last discharge, it's adding one to the flag instead of keeping the flag the same.

Comment: I have made the changes in the code. Now try and let me know if you face any difficulty.

Comment: This one variation seems to throw everything off, I will add the example in my question.

Comment: I think for G, maybe the same day admission and discharge is the issue, though I don't know why.  Much appreciated!

Comment: I have made the another logic which is more efficient. Use the updated code and it solves all the combinations :)

Comment: For G, the indicator should be 1,1,2,3.  Since 06May2015 and 08Sep2015 are more than 1 day apart even though they have the same loc_num.  Argh, sorry, this data is finnicky!

Comment: No No, g has 4 rows, 1st and 2nd rows have indicator 1 because it satisfies the criteria (30apr-01may and same location). 2nd and 3rd or 3rd and 4th row does not match the criteria, therefore, 3rd and 4th row is filled with the seq 1,2

Comment: How do I alter the code so that 3rd and 4th row is 3,4?  I need to take the minimum admission and maximum discharge by indicator in a further step and I realized that would group the 08Sep2015 and 12Sep2015 row into the same episode as the previous two.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142844/discussion-between-g-arima-and-pinkyl).